# Can not create specification that will check class of field

Tags: java, spring, jpa, predicate

Entity Order contains field:

`@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private AbstractRequester requester;`

I wanna get data by type this field.

I created specification like in documentation, but on

`page = orderRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);`

Get Exception

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: class of: ...order.Order`

My specs:

```
@Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Order> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    Predicate megaPredicate = cb.conjunction();`
    ...
megaPredicate = cb.and(megaPredicate, cb.and(
                            cb.equal(root.get("requester").type(), cb.literal(PersonRequester.class))
...
return megaPredicate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the discriminator column in your query and that's illegal.

Instead, execute your query on the `PersonRequester` directly and remove the offending clause from `megaPredicate`.